# json items are not displayed in listview

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to bookmark my app but I have some charges in my code, below I'll explain my problems.

Let's start with my adapter memes.class

```
public class memes{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;
    private Boolean mIsFavourite;

    public memes(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public Boolean getmIsFavourite() {
        return mIsFavourite;
    }

    public void setmIsFavourite(Boolean mIsFavouriteResource) {
        this.mIsFavourite = mIsFavouriteResource;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    public int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }

}
```

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<memes> item;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;
    String[] Nomes = new String[]{"Compartilhar", "Add Favoritos"};
    List<memes> favoriteMemes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();
        //itens
        item.add(new memes("item 1", R.raw.audio1));
        item.add(new memes("item 2", R.raw.audio2));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Menu");
                builder.setItems(MainActivity.this.Nomes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                sendWhatsAppAudio(position);
                                return;
                            case 1:
                                //set item true
                                item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
                                return;
                            default:
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

This is where I send the items to the other activity

```
//Here is the mess.
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.abreFavoritos:
                for(int i=0;i<lv.getAdapter().getCount();i++){
                    memes fMeme = (memes)lv.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                    //mIsFavourite in my code it turns red
                    //what should I put after the item. to work?
                    if (item.mIsFavourite()) {
                        favoriteMemes.add(fMeme);
                    }
                }
                intent = new Intent(this, Favoritos.class);

                intent.putExtra("favoritos", new Gson().toJson(favoriteMemes));
                    startActivity(intent);

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Now finally activity in which we place the Favoritos.class

```
public class Favoritos extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);

        String memesString = getIntent().getStringExtra("favoritos");
        memes[] fMemes = new Gson().fromJson(memesString,memes[].class);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fMemes);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Items are not displayed with this code.

I think my problem is in `if (item.mIsFavorite ())` but I have no idea what to put here.

one more thing, on the second activity how would I remove the items?

and tbm could I recommend a good tutorial from SharedPreferences so I can use that case.

Thank you

Comment: try debugging it

Comment: I tried but the items are not displayed in the favorite activity

Comment: 1. Check whether `memesString` in Favoritos empty. 2. Check `favoriteMemes` contains non-null data in `onOptionsItemSelected` before start an intent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!